# Reduce the size of "Figure" in the caption

Tags: floats, captions

[image]

How to decrease the size and color of the "Figure" in the caption of \documentclass{beamer}?
I have attached a picture of the caption. Thank you so much

Comment: Please provide MWE  (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem. It is high probability that you somewhere set `\setbeamerfont` so, that produce your result, but without seeing a MWE is difficult to say some certain.

Comment: It's your **5th question**, time to read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} % just needed for the example
\usepackage{caption} % provides \captionof
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny} % <------ Adapt size as you want.

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw(0,0)circle(2pt);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \captionof{figure}{text}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please try to provide a MWE next time so we can see which packages and settings you use and how you create your figures.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me.